# Upload div background url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently i am working on faking a social media website using: Javascript, Jquery, html and css. Most of the things have gone quite well. I want my website to feel more like a social media site though. This is where the problem starts. For a few pages i used an image as a background in the body. Like this:

```
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
    background-image: url("../pictures/straatbackground.jpg");
}
```

For the pages i don`t want this background to show up i just use:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
$("body").css("background-image", "none");
```

However, now i can`t use background-image and instead i am using background: url. It works perfectly in this css part i wrote:

```
.circular {
  width: 28%;
  height: 90%;
  margin-left:35%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  background: url(../pictures/profielfototje.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  }
```

However, if i want to change it my code so i can upload a file and change the background my code fails. It looks like this:

```
$(".circular").click(function(){
    var uploadplaatje = $(".circular").fileupload().val();
$('.circular').css("background", "url(uploadplaatje)");



}); // click
```

Sadly i am not experienced enough to come up with a solution myself. Can anyone help me and explain to me how i can change the background of my div by clicking it and uploading a picture.

Forever grateful,

Joep (code newby)

Answer (score 0):

The `uploadplaatje` variable is not being parsed, here is the correct call:

```
$('.circular').css("background", "url(" + uploadplaatje + ")");
```

(Assuming that you have checked the content of the variable)